# When is a variable local and when global?

Tags: bash, variable, function

Consider the following two functions:

```
f1() {
  if [ "$a" == "" ]; then
    a="0";
  else
    a=$(($a+1));
  fi;
  echo "$a";
}

f2() {
  echo "f1(): $($1)";
}
```

If I call `f1` multiple times `a` will be incremented as expected:

```
$ f1
0
$ f1
1
$ f1
2
```

But if I call `f1` from `f2` `a` remains `0`:

```
$ f2 "f1"
f1(): 0
$ f2 "f1"
f1(): 0
```

I've heard (and also experienced) that variables declared in functions are global. Then why is there such a difference? Is it a special case or don't I call `f1` from `f2` in a correct way?

Ok, I've just noticed that changing `f2` definition to:

```
f2() {
  eval "$1";
}
```

solves the problem, but it would still be interesting to know what the purpose of the first kind of call is `$($1)`. What does it do exactly?

I've also noticed that I'm not able to assign the "return" value of `f1` to a variable in `f2`.

```
f2() {
  ...
  res=$(eval "$1");
  ...
}
```

`res` will be the same after every call `f2 "f1"`

Why?

Comment: In `$(f1)`, `f1` is executed in a subshell

Comment: Compare: `a=0; ( a=$((a+1)); ); { a=$((a+1)); }; echo $a` (outputs `1`)

Comment: Looking at your first set of code `f1` will always return `0`, as `a` is never set!

Comment: Your question is unclear, and so is your syntax. This appears to be more of a chat, state what you want explaining. Your first code is doing what is expected as `a` is always `""` so `0`!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Why is a always "" ? If it is global then it should become 0+1=1 by the next call.

Comment: It's not global the way your using it. To be global create that variable outside the `f1` function

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I don't think you've read my question carefully.

Comment: You say when you call `f1` the variable increments? I am trying the same thing on my end but I don't see any increment!

Comment: @ka3ak Everything inside `$(command)` is executed in a subshell. Global or local is irrelevant, because no variable assignments in a subshell affect the parent shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank anyone for comments mentioning subshell. However I want to give a more detailed answer.

Each time `f1` is called from `f2` a new subshell will be created and only the 3 instructions will be executed.

```
    f1() {
1      if [ "$a" == "" ]; then
2        a="0";
      else
        a=$(($a+1));
      fi;
3      echo "$a";
    }
```

`a` becomes global and initialized in the subshell (at least on my system, because repetitive `f1` calls increment `a`). But `a` doesn't exist in the next created subshell.

Answer (score 0):

In f1 the value of `a` is global (in bash), it would be local if `a` is defined with:

```
local a
```

Change f1 definition to:

```
f1() {
       local a
       if [ "$a" == "" ]; then
           a="0";
       else
           a=$(($a+1));
       fi;
           echo "$a";
     }
```

to make the variable local.

For f2:
f2 is called in a sub shell $(f2). Sub shells variables don't affect the parent.